# Play 2.6 Ebeans relationship error

Tags: playframework, one-to-many, ebean, many-to-one, playframework-2.6

```
   Posts Model

  /*set many to one relation with Privacy_Level model*/
  @ManyToOne//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "privacy_level_id",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public Privacy_Level privacy_level_t;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Privacy_Level Model

  /*set one to many relation with Posts model*/
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "privacy_level_t")
  public List<Posts> posts;

  /*set many to one relation with Table_Status model*/
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "status",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public Table_Status table_status;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Table_Status Model

  /*set many to one relation with Privacy_level table*/
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table_status")
  public List<Privacy_Level> privacy_level;
```

I have linked the `Posts` model with the `Privacy_Level` model using a
manytoone/onetomany relationship while the `Table_Status` model with `Privacy_Level`
model using a many to one/one to many relationship as well.

Now I need to access a value in `Table_Status` through a `Posts` object as shown below:

```
post.privacy_level_t.table_status.getDes()
```

This worked fine in Play 2.5 but after migrating to Play 2.6 this returns a null value.
I can however access a `Privacy_Level` value using `post.privacy_level_t.getDes()` but 
trying to access a value one step further down the hierarchy line returns an error.

I checked through the Play migration guide but could not find anything related to this
issue.

**UPDATE**

This is the function that i'm having the mentioned issue.

```
 private boolean getPostsDetail(List<Posts> post_list){
       home_page_posts = Json.newArray();
       for(Posts post:post_list) {

           if(!post.privacy_level_t.table_status.getDes().equals("activated")) continue;
           switch (post.post_types.getPost_type_name()){
               case "Star_Rating":
                   getArrayNodeForNonAnonyStarPost(post);
                   continue;
               case "Text_Poll":
                   getArrayNodeForNonAnonyPollPost(post);
                   continue;
               case "Image_Poll":
                   getArrayNodeForNonAnonyPollPost(post);
                   continue;
               case "star_rating_post_other_detail":
                   getArrayNodeForAnonyStarPost(post);
                   continue;
               default:
                   continue;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
```

The code inside the if condition returns a NullPointerException in Play 2.6

Comment: What is `getDes()` ? Can you share your code Model by Model instead of putting everything together? It's confusing.

Comment: @Zenoo getDes() is a public getter method inside the Table_Status model.
This code works fine in Play 2.5 but after migrating to 2.6 it stopped working.
I broke down the relationships according to their models/classes as you requested.

Comment: In your example, how do you fetch `post` ? Do you use a `Finder` ? Please share the context of the code producing the error.

Comment: Finder method in Play 2.5:
public static Finder<Long, Privacy_Level> find = new Finder<Long, Privacy_Level>(Long.class, Privacy_Level.class);

Finder method in Play 2.6:

public static Finder<Long, Privacy_Level> find = new Finder<Long, Privacy_Level>(Privacy_Level.class);

Comment: Can you also share where the `post_list` parameter is created/fetched ?

Comment: @Zenoo The posts_list parameter is successfully received inside the function.
I can access post.privacy_level.getDes() but the error occurs when I try to access post.privacy_level.table_status.getDes().
If I call post.privacy_level.getDes() and then call post.privacy_level.table_status.getDes() in the preceeding line, the value is successfully returned!

Comment: @Zenoo Correction: not in the preceeding line but in the following line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173672/discussion-between-zenoo-and-crazydroid).